# Autoreloading of django files on server

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm using centos, apache, mod_wsgi on server for django project.

After uploading over sftp of changed project files site opens with changes and without changes randomly.

I think, that changes should not be applied before restarting apache. Isn't it?

Apache settings

```
<VirtualHost *:88>
ServerName h1.ru

UseCanonicalName Off
ServerAdmin  "admin@h1.ru"
DocumentRoot /var/www/h1/h1.ru/
AllowEncodedSlashes On

WSGIDaemonProcess h1 processes=4
#WSGIProcessGroup h1


WSGIScriptAlias /site /var/www/h1/pyh1/h1/wsgi.py
Alias /static /var/www/h1/pyh1/static

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLEngine off
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/h1/h1.ru>
    php_admin_flag engine on
    php_admin_flag safe_mode off
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/h1/h1.ru:/tmp"
    Options -Includes -ExecCGI
</Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "h1.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application 
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode and consider switching to mod_wsgi daemon mode as well, as using embedded mode with Apache prefork MPM and PHP is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not true. Normally mod_wsgi will run in multiple separate processes, managing their startup and shutdown automatically. When a new process starts, Python code will be loaded from disk as it is imported, so that process will run with the newest versions of any files. Meanwhile, any processes that were already alive will use the versions they had previously loaded, so will not reflect the changes (unless a little-used code path is activated which leads to importing a so-far-unimported module).

Certainly the only way to be sure you have the latest choose in all processes is to restart Apache.